# Possible to pass closure into spread operator

Tags: groovy

Is it possible to use a closure with the spread operator with Groovy.

e.g.

```
def numbers = [4,8]
def numbersPlusTen = numbers*.{it -> it + 10}
```

Or can the spread operator only ever work on a method or property?

Comment: Just to make sure: you know about `collect` right? `def numbersPlusTen = numbers?.collect {it -> it + 10}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the spread dot operator only works on methods. However in your example you can use some meta programming to make this work.

```
​def numbers = [4,8]
java.lang.Integer.metaClass.something = {delegate + 10}
def numbersPlusTen = numbers*.​something()​
```

Answer (score 4):

Or I would just do

```
def numbers = [4,8]
def numbersPlusTen = numbers*.plus(10)
```

if I want to add 10. :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use List's each() method for even more complex operation, not just plus():

```
list.each({item -> item.callSomeMethod(item.getSomeProperty()+1)})
```

so your example with implicit arg would be:

```
def numbersPlusTen = []
numbers.each({numbersPlusTen << it+10})
```

spread operator may also be used in front:

```
def args = [4,8]
function f(int x, int y) {x+y}
f(*args)
```